# How do I add more words to the mediawiki UniversalLanguageSelector extension

Tags: translation, mediawiki, wiki

I have added some contents to the mediawiki sidebar(**Mediawiki:Sidebar**). When I changed the language from English to Malayalam using the UniversalLanguageSelector, everything in the sidebar except the newly added contents got translated. My question:

**What do I do to get all the sidebar contents to be translated to Malayalam?**
**Can I add those contents along with the translations to some file in the extension's folder so that it also will get translated?**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to localize the sidebar, is to use system message as variables. E.g., rather than adding the link `*mw-mainpage-url|My mainpage` in English, `*mw-mainpage-url|Min huvudsida` in Swedish, etc, just do `*mw-mainpage-url|mainpage-description` in `MediaWiki:Sidebar`, and then use `mainpage-description/en`, `mainpage-description/sv`, etc to change the translation of that part of the sidebar. This way you only need to change the sidebar layout in one place, and you can make use of the many translations already available, as well as create your own, custom system messages, by adding pages to the MediaWiki namespace.

Note that sidebar contents is [aggressively cached](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar). You might need to purge your pages.

Also note that `$wgUseDatabaseMessages` must be true (default).

Comment: I have edited Mediawiki:Sidebar/ml and changed the language to malayalam using the Universal Language Selector but the sidebar did not change.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you put `?uselang=ml` at the end of the url?

Comment: Also: Do you by any change have `$wgEnableSidebarCache` set to true in `LocalSettings.php`? Default is `false`. Finally, what MediaWiki version are you using?

Comment: I am using MW 1.23. Tried with `?uselang=ml` but nothing happened except a 'create page' suggestion. Also `$wgEnableSidebarCache` is not set.

Comment: Use `&uselang=ml` if you already have a question mark in the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65122/discussion-between-leo-and-arshad-muhammed).